# How to generate icon programmatically and use it instead of a shortcut icon?

Tags: java, android, icons, android-drawable, shortcut

Are there any ways to programmatically generate an icon (a constant background, and text in the centre (from a variable that can change)) and use it instead of a shortcut icon?

Comment: This can only be achieved through a custom launcher. The app cannot change its icon without being upversioned.

Comment: @JakeB, I'm talking about shortcut icon, not about app icon. To put an icon into shortcut I use Intent extra:         intent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.shortcut.ICON_RESOURCE", Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.icon)); I this that I can generate it programmatically... But don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Android's ShortcutManager might best suit your needs here as it allows static and dynamic generation of shortcuts.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html#dynamic

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);

ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, SHORTCUT_ID)
    .setShortLabel("My Shortcut")
    .setLongLabel("This is my shortcut")
    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.mipmap))
    .setIntent(SHORTCUT_ACTION)
    .build();

shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(shortcut));
```